# How to find if email has spammed

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability

We are sending out emails from SFMC with delivery rate ~100%. Does it mean that all emails are being delivered to customer's inbox. Is there a way to find if some of those emails may have spammed.

Thanks,
Sanchit

Answer (score 2):

The metric you are looking for is inbox placement rate. This indicates what number of emails have indeed reached the inbox. This is difficult to measure without a dedicated ISP integration - offered by a.o. Return Path.

Inbox placement rates are most often ISP specific, and looking at domain open rates can give an indication of deliverability issues - especially when experiencing sudden and significant drops.

Let’s say your open rates are averaging 30%. Your Microsoft domains (msn.com, Hotmail.com) are seeing on average 25%, but suddenly drop to 10-12% for consecutive sends. It is a sign of further investigation being required - which can be done using ISP specific tools, or by reaching out to postmaster of that specific domain.

You can also log a support ticket with Salesforce, and ask them for help with resolving some of your deliverability related problems.

Answer (score 1):

There's typically no way to tell if an email was delivered to a spam folder, as emails are typically sorted to a spam folder/deleted/blocked/etc after delivery, not during the SMTP process. The delivery rate simply shows that emails were received by an email inbox. For example, non-existent email inboxes or invalid mail domains would lower your delivery rate.

Comment: Services like Return Path may help you find out info about reputation and inbox placement, but they are extra cost